# Factory Girl and lazy initialization while running db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, factory-bot

I have a factory like that:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :member_data,
          :class => Member do
    first_name 'fn_member'
    last_name 'ln_member'
  end
end
```

When I run `db:migrate`, FactoryGirl is called before the creation of the `Member` table. And I got some errors like "attribute not found". I found while searching the internet that some things must be lazy initialized, eg:

```
Factory.define :order do |f|
  ...
  f.code_id Code.first
end
```

must be:

```
Factory.define :order do |f|
  ...
  f.code_id { Code.first }
end
```

And indeed, if I remove `:class => Member` the migration succeeds. But how can I lazily define the factory `:class` ???

Thanks

Comment: Did you try putting it in quotes? (`factory :member_data, :class => "Member" ...`)

Comment: thanks, that was too obvious :) create an answer so that I can accept it ; `:class => :Member` is working too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` allows `:class_name => "ClassNameInQuotes"` in its associations, and FactoryGirl can do this too. **Just put the class name in quotes.**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :member_data, :class => "Member" do
    first_name 'fn_member'
    last_name 'ln_member'
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you know why this is needed?? Why factory girl does it run before migration?

Comment: @RafaelCosta not sure but seems it's just because of process. I faced with similar problem recently and it was in such way: `rake` initializes application in `environment.rb`, it requires all files (including factories), FactoryGirl executes its code and tries to create fields (in my case) and for sure can't find DB, because I only trying to create this!